# Is there a way for the C++ compiler to warn for unsafe enum class to integer overflow?

Tags: c++, enums, static-cast

There are uses of enum classes in my codebase, where we need to convert to integers for low level functions.

There are static casts to `uint8_t` all over, assuming the `enum` has a small number of values.

As the size of our enums grow past fitting in a `uint8_t`, for example adding the 257th element to the enum, the casts will output the wrong value. Is there a way for the compiler to warn me of such narrowing/overflow?

```cpp
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>

enum class Color: uint32_t{ red, green, blue, orange=0xFFFFFFFF };
enum class Animal { dog, cat, frog=0xFFF };

int main(){
    Color g = Color::green;
    auto gg = static_cast<uint8_t>(g);
    Color f = Color::orange;
    auto ff = static_cast<uint8_t>(f);
    Animal frog = Animal::frog;
    auto nFrog = static_cast<uint8_t>(frog);
    printf("Casted value of red: 0x%x\n", gg);
    printf("Casted value of orange: 0x%x\n", ff);
    printf("Casted value of frog: 0x%x\n", nFrog);

    return 0;
}
```

```
Casted value of red: 0x1
Casted value of orange: 0xff
Casted value of frog: 0xff
```

I tried adding `-Wall`, `-WPedantic`, however nothing warns me that the integer value of `orange` will overflow in the cast.

I can slowly adopt the usage of `using std::underlying_type`, but I'd like the compiler to yell at me instead.

Requirements:

- Works with scoped enum (enum class)
  Desires:
- Maintainable for large enums that are messy/out of order

Comment: There's no way of knowing if it *will* until runtime, I'm not sure C++ looks that far ahead. It's only a possibility when compiling. When you start wrecking around with `static_cast` it's assumed you know what you're doing and you're aware of the risks.

Comment: What you can do, is to declare enum as `enum class Color: uint8_t` and use equivalent of C++23's `std::to_underlying()` to cast instead of `static_cast`.

Comment: Why do you need to declare the Color anum as an uint32_t value?  Wouldn't it be easier to declare all your affected enums as being of uint8_t size?

Comment: You can use `static_assert()` to verify an enum value is in the desired range before casting it, eg: `static_assert(std::underlying_type_t<Color>(Color::orange) <= std::numeric_limits<uint8_t>::max(), "Orange overflows!");` ([Demo](https://ideone.com/hG5fly)) That doesn't help for enum variables assigned at runtime, though. Maybe use a runtime `assert()` instead.

Comment: "the enum has a small number of values" If the underlying type is uint32_t, that's the values the enum has (not the set of values of the enumerators).

Comment: Clang and GCC have a compiler flag `-Wconversion` which will warn of implicit lossy conversions.  This won't work on the code you show, because you are **explicitly** casting the enum to `uint8_t`.  That cast means that you want the lossy conversion.

Comment: @tadman Why does it have to be only at runtime? The enum size is known at compile time?

Comment: @MichaëlRoy Well the enums don't actually declare their size. Previous programmers assumed they would only take up 8 bits, but now it no longer fits, so no. It is impossible to declare the enums strictly as uint8_t because there will soon be more than 255 values in them.

Comment: @DrewDormann Because enum class does not allow implicit conversion, is `-Wconversion` relevant?

Comment: @JaMiT By and large, the enums sizes are not declared explicitly. They are usually sized automatically. However, some programmers made assumptions they would only be a uint8, and I need a way to guarantee that is no longer done. Either at the compiler, or a static analysis tool. However, in some places, C-style casts to `uint8_t` are used, which supposedly are hard to find with static analysis tools.

Comment: You say sized automatically but the post uses scoped enumerations (always int if not specified otherwise). Which is it?

Comment: @RyanFriedman  Of course, you can specify the size of enums, you are even already doing so.  For 1 byte long enums, change your declaration to: `enum class Color : uint8_t { /*...*/ };`

Comment: @JeffGarrett Both methods are used throughout the code; I have updated the example to show it.

Answer (score 1):

You could encapsulate your enums into a struct with a conversion operator which checks if the target type is large enough:

```
struct Animal {
    // someone added cow which makes it not fit into uint8 anymore:
    enum Animal_enum { dog, cat, frog=0xFF, cow } value;

    Animal(Animal_enum x) : value(x) {}

    template<class T>
    inline operator T() {
        static_assert( cow <= std::numeric_limits<T>::max(), "conversion is unsafe!");
        return T(value);
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
int main() {
    Animal a = Animal::cow; // You can still use prior enum names
    int16_t x = a; // this is fine

    // these fail at compile time:
    // uint8_t y = a;
    // static_cast<uint8_t>(a); // fails even if value is not used

    // this works:
    uint8_t y = static_cast<uint16_t>(a); // implicit conversion after explicit conversion

    return x + y;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer; this doesn't meet my needs because you are not using a scoped enumeration. We intentionally want to prevent implicit casting on our enums because they are very easy to confuse. If you can modify it to use a scoped enum, like in my example, I would accept it. That said, it does require you to manually maintain the highest value in the enum in the `T()` operator, which may not be easy to do.

Comment: Just replacing `enum Animal_enum` by `enum class Animal_enum` will make using `Animal::cow` fail -- unless one defines `static const` members for every value of `Animal_enum` inside `Animal`. Maybe I can think of a better solution. BTW: Could you please edit your question to include all clarifications which you only put into comments so far? E.g., (at least in your question) you did not specifically write that you strictly require scoped enumerations.

Comment: Regarding maintaining the highest member: Would `std::numeric_limits<std::underlying_type<Animal_enum> >::max() <= std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` work for you? You'd need to explicitly declare the underlying type as `uint16_t` or `uint8_t` if you want to allow that conversion, but the compiler will prohibit you from exceeding that range. Also, if the underlying type was `uint16_t`, conversions to `int16_t` would not be possible, of course.

Comment: It's in the title, and the example shows an enum class. I will add this clarification. Yes, that would be ideal for the compiler to automatically detect it. Enforcing size on enums is reasonable.